# Re-run for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop.now some values return NA.I would like to re run the for loop only for the values that have results NA and not for all the values.below is what I am using right now.this re runs the for loop for all the values.

```
while(df[2] == NA){

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

#do something

}}
```

df is the data frame
first column of df has some values and second column stores the result of the corresponding value.

Comment: If it is `NA` and not a string `"NA"`, then use `is.na()` function. Also, if you explain more `#do something` bit of your code, maybe there will be no need `forloop` and `while`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(sum(is.na(df[2])>0){

for(i in which(is.na(df[2])){

#do something

}}
```